Есть ли алгоритм для решения задачи без перебора?
Дано натуральное число n.
Представить данное число n в виде суммы двух целых чисел x, y (x, y >= 0), в которых не было бы цифр 8 и 9, и первое из слагаемых было бы минимально возможным.
Например: 859 = 102 + 757 и 849 = 72 + 777.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Уточните - имеется в виду "без полного перебора", то есть по сути математически? Или подойдет алгоритм, который сузит поиск, но перебирать все-таки придется?

@Духсообщества Бот: Да ну!

Вот что я думаю. Берём число 859. Вычисляем максимально близкое к нему без 8 и 9. Это число 777. Далее, 859 - 777 = 82. Ближайшее к 82 без 8 и 9 - это 100. Поскольку из последней цифры числа 859 мы вычли 2, надо к 100 прибавить 2. Пример 2: 19969 > 17777 > 19969 - 17777 = 2192 > 2200 > 2202 > 19969 = 2202 + 17767. Строго математически доказать не могу.

@OldSkull . Ближайшее к 82 без 8 и 9 - это 100 - а с какой стороны ближайшее? например 77 ближе к 82 чем 100

@Grundy, если из из 82 вычесть 5, чтобы получить 77, то к 777 надо будет прибавить 5, тогда получится 782

Люто бешено плюсую! Крутая задача! Двое суток потратил на разные подходы. Спасибо! У вас есть ещё?

step_down(k) ищет ближайшее число меньшее или равное k свободное от восьмёрок и девяток. Для этого ищем самую старшую восьмёрку-девятку и начиная с этого места меняем хвост числа на сплошные семёрки:
19969
17777
step_up(k) делает такой же поиск в сторону больших чисел. Снова ищем старшую восьмёрку-девятку, но теперь, если перед ней есть семёрки они тоже включаются. Найденный хвост отрезается, начало числа увеличивается на единицу, на место хвоста вписываются нули:
1277953
12
13
1300000
decompose(n) разбивает n на слагаемые a, b. Начальные значения 0, n. Если в слагаемом b есть восьмёрки-девятки, оно заменяется ближайшим меньшим, свободным от них. Значение a обновляется.
Если в слагаемом a есть восьмёрки-девятки, оно заменяется ближайшим большим, свободным от них. Значение b обновляется.
Если оба слагаемых свободны от восьмёрок-девяток, это ответ. Так как пары a, b перебираются от нуля по возрастанию a, мы получаем пару с минимальным первым слагаемым:
Сложность – куб числа цифр O(ln3n) (это в предположении что перевод int ⇄ str делается за логарифм). Если убрать преобразования и всю арифметику сделать на десятичных строках можно получить квадрат логарифма O(ln2n).
import re


def step_down(k):
    s = str(k)
    m = re.search('[89]', s)
    if m is None:
        return k
    i = m.start(0)
    return int(s[:i] + '7' * (len(s) - i))


def step_up(k):
    s = str(k)
    m = re.search('7*[89]', s)
    if m is None:
        return k
    i = m.start(0)
    return int(str(int('0' + s[:i]) + 1) + '0' * (len(s) - i))


def decompose(n):
    a, b = 0, n
    while True:
        b2 = step_down(b)
        if b2 == b:
            break
        a, b = n - b2, b2
        a2 = step_up(a)
        if a2 == a:
            break
        a, b = a2, n - a2
    return a, b


print(*decompose(int(input())))


$ echo 859 | python decompose.py
102 757

$ echo 849 | python decompose.py
72 777

$ echo 19969 | python decompose.py
2202 17767


P.S. Поиск таких n при которых этот алгоритм работает медленнее всего – не плохая задача сама по себе.

@contrlccontrlc , я согласен. rotabor решил задачу двеннадцать часов назад. Алгоритмы почти совпадают. Галочка его по  праву.

@OldScul вроде раньше опубликовал, но я не проверял его решение.

В конце концов, это право автора вопроса. Есть много критериев.

@rotabor, в его ответе неудачно обработано 7777777778 в левом слагаемом. Он перенос по одной позиции тащит. У вас и у меня сразу возвращается правильное верхнее число. Но его алгоритм выглядит вполне рабочим.

Раньше я быдлокодил в основном на Delphi, так что прошу прощения, если что...

Берём число 859.
Вычисляем максимально близкое к нему без 8 и 9. Это число 777.
Далее вычисляем разность: 859 - 777 = 82.
Ближайшее к 82 число без 8 и 9 - это 100. Поскольку из последней цифры числа 859 мы вычли 2, надо к 100 прибавить 2. Получаем 859 = 102 + 757

import numpy as np

# find maximal number which is <= num and does not contain 8 and 9
# ex: 849 => 777; # 178 => 177; # 234 => 234
def normalize_right_part(num):
    num_arr = np.array(tuple(str(num)))
    m = np.argmax(num_arr > '7')
    if m > 0 or num_arr[0] > '7':
        num_arr[m:] = '7'
    
    return int( ''.join(num_arr) )

# if num does not contains 8 or 9 then leave it as is
# otherwise round it up to nearest number which does not contain 8 and 9
# ex: 849 => 1000; # 178 => 200; 234 => 234; 158 => 160
def normalize_left_part(num):
    num_arr = np.fromiter(str(num), dtype=int)

    m = np.argmax(num_arr > 7)
    if m == 0 and num_arr[0] < 8:
        return num

    increase = False

    for i in range(0, m+1):
        if increase:
            num_arr[m-i] += 1
            increase = False
        
        if num_arr[m-i] > 7:
            num_arr[m-i] = 0
            increase = True

    num_arr[m:] = 0

    if increase:
        num_arr = np.insert(num_arr, 0, 1)

    return int( ''.join(num_arr.astype(dtype=str)) )

# find number = a + b, where a and b don't contain 8 and 9
# and a is the minimal possible
def find_sum(num):
    right_part = normalize_right_part(num)
    left_part  = num - right_part

    while True:
        left_part = normalize_left_part(left_part)
        right_part = num - left_part
        
        right_part_new = normalize_right_part(right_part)

        if right_part_new == right_part:
            break
        
        left_part += right_part - right_part_new

    return left_part, right_part

tio.run
100 = 0 + 100
107 = 0 + 107
108 = 1 + 107
154 = 0 + 154
777 = 0 + 777
821 = 44 + 777
849 = 72 + 777
853 = 76 + 777
859 = 102 + 757
863 = 100 + 763
867 = 100 + 767
890 = 113 + 777
899 = 122 + 777
900 = 123 + 777
985 = 210 + 775
993 = 216 + 777
880088 = 102311 + 777777
821000849 = 43223072 + 777777777
8000000001 = 222222224 + 7777777777
858585858585 = 101010101010 + 757575757575


Есть числа, для которых функцию find_sum нужно повторять несколько раз. Например: 858585858585 - 777777777777 = 80808080808; 858585858585 - 100000000000 = 758585858585; и т. д.

Добавил ссылку на онлайн-компилятор и вывод.

Да, надо функцию normalize_left_part слегка переделать

@contrlccontrlc, Исправил, проверяйте

@OldSkull, Простая проверка: https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1rEU

@contrlccontrlc, Теперь, вроде, работает. По крайней мере, в Вашей сравнилке расхождений нет. Однако, пришлось-таки цикл сделать (но это и не полный перебор; я посчитал -- получилось максимум 5 попыток). Думаю, есть способ и без цикла, но математик из меня никакой. Тем не менее, прошу прощения за ложную надежду.

хм... а какая сложность в итоге и насколько это лучше перебора? есть ли гарантия что мы выйдем из бесконечного цикла? Может существуют такие входные данные, на которых программа зацикливается?

@АндрейNOP, насколько лучше? Например, для числа 858585 потребуется 101010 попыток прямого перебора и 3 попытки моего. Касательно гарантий: ни я, ни мой код ничего не гарантируем. В комментарии к вопросу я подчеркнул, что не могу доказать свой подход строго математически. По поводу сложности bigocalc говорит: the overall time complexity can be considered O(d^2) in the worst case (where d is the number of digits in the number),... the space complexity is O(1).

С трудом продрался через numpy. Это рабочий алгоритм. Плюсик ваш.

Окончательное решение:
def ut(x):
  sx = '0' + str(x)
  lx = len(sx)
  for i in range(lx):
    if sx[i] < '7':
      j = i
    elif sx[i] > '7':
      sx = str(int(sx[:j + 1]) + 1) + '0' * (lx - j - 1)
      break
  return int(sx)

def dt(x):
  sx = str(x)
  lx = len(sx)
  for i in range(lx):
    if sx[i] > '7':
      sx = sx[:i] + '7' * (lx - i)
      break
  return int(sx)

def p(x):
  y = x - dt(x)
  y, ym = x - dt(x - ut(y)), y
  while (y != ym):
    y, ym = x - dt(x - ut(y)), y
  print('Result: ', x, y, x - y)

p(100)
p(107)
p(108)
p(777)
p(849)
p(853)
p(859)
p(863)
p(890)
p(899)
p(900)
p(985)
p(993)


Result:  100 0 100
Result:  107 0 107
Result:  108 1 107
Result:  777 0 777
Result:  849 72 777
Result:  853 76 777
Result:  859 102 757
Result:  863 100 763
Result:  890 113 777
Result:  899 122 777
Result:  900 123 777
Result:  985 210 775
Result:  993 216 777

Алгоритм:

ut выдаёт ближайшее большее семёрочное число.
dt выдаёт ближайшее меньшее семёрочное число.
p ищет схождение ut и dt.

Из области занимательной математики
Казалось бы, 7 - большое число по отношению к 10, и среди однозначных чисел, включая 0, 8 чисел годных и всего 2 - нет, то есть годных 80%. Но с ростом количества разрядов N доля годных чисел уменьшается: для N = 9 (1 000 000 000 чисел) годных оказывается меньше 13,5% (8 ^ 9). Тем не менее, любое число можно представить суммой двух годных чисел. И число (8/10) ^ N стремительно уменьшается с ростом N!
Очевидно, что такой фокус (представить число суммой двух чисел с ограничением по используемым цифрам) можно проделать вплоть до цифры 5.
Что касается вопроса Станислава о сходимости поиска, то мне кажется, что плохих чисел тут нет, сходимость очень хорошая. Самые плохие числа - периодические, в которых группа цифр [<8]+[>7]+ повторяется. Например, числу '59' * 20 нужно 20 итераций. Судя по всему, каждому переходу границы нужна одна итерация.

863 = 100 + 763, ваша программа выводит 863 = 106 + 757; 100 = 0 + 100; 108 = 1 + 107 и т. д.

Простая проверка перебором: https://www.online-python.com/f2pIxtgn73

Какая-то муть... Перенос вообще не нужен т. к. он никогда не возникает.

@rotabor, упс, теперь понял...

@rotabor, прошу прощения.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Да ну, всё норм.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Алгоритм один и тот же, и число итераций должно совпадать.

@rotabor, оно и совпадает. Я просто неудачно расписал итерацию. Сейчас уже исправлено.

Осталось избавиться от строчных преобразований и выграть одну степень логарифма. Но код больно сложный получается. А выгода большинству не очевидно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Тогда придётся самому искать цифры, что одно и то же. Надеюсь, в Python str сделана на низком уровне.

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

Каждая цифра числа превращается в сумму двух: max(x-7, 0) + min(x, 7). Переноса нет. Потом для каждого фрагмента 10 в первом числе проверяем, можем ли мы заменить эти 10 на меньшее число, чтобы в правом разряде второго числа получилось 7, и, если да, то заменяем. tio.run
def solve(x):
  a = []
  b = []

  while x:
    d = x % 10
    x //= 10

    a.append(max(d-7, 0))
    b.append(min(d, 7))

  for i in range(len(a)-1, 1, -1):
    if a[i] == 1 and a[i-1] == 0 and b[i-1] < 5:
      a[i] = 0
      a[i-1] = b[i-1] + 3
      b[i-1] = 7

  l = 0
  r = 0

  for d in a[::-1]:
    l = l*10 + d

  for d in b[::-1]:
    r = r*10 + d
  
  return (l,r)
  

for x in [100, 107, 108, 777, 821, 849, 853, 859, 863, 867, 890, 899, 900, 985, 993, 880088, 821000849, 8000000001]:
  a,b = solve(x)
  print(x, "=", a, "+", b, x == a + b)

100 = 0 + 100 True
107 = 0 + 107 True
108 = 1 + 107 True
777 = 0 + 777 True
821 = 50 + 771 True
849 = 72 + 777 True
853 = 100 + 753 True
859 = 102 + 757 True
863 = 100 + 763 True
867 = 100 + 767 True
890 = 120 + 770 True
899 = 122 + 777 True
900 = 200 + 700 True
985 = 210 + 775 True
993 = 220 + 773 True
880088 = 103011 + 777077 True
821000849 = 50000072 + 771000777 True
8000000001 = 300000000 + 7700000001 True


849 = 72 + 777 :-(

@rotabor, откуда? 849 = 102 + 747 у меня.

@rotabor, а блин. Понял. Надо 72, а у меня 102. Эх...

@rotabor, кажется, готово?

Нее... 853=777+76. Тут граничное число 154=77+77.

@rotabor, ну да, десятка - и есть два разряда.

795 = 20 + 775 = 18 + 777

@АндрейNOP, так в 18 есть цифра 8, а надо без неё. Вроде 20 правильно?

@rotabor, 154=0+154 - у меня верно. Про 853 надо подумать.

@Qwertiy, согласен, туплю

Для начала нужно разделить число на цифры:
n = 859 # или другое число
x = 0 # первое слагаемое
y = 0 # второе слагаемое

# ------- делим число на цифры
digits = [] # список для цифр n
digits.append(n % 10) # первая цифра

# для остальных цифр
div_a_mod_num = 10
i=0
sub_num = digits[0] # число для вычета
while n > div_a_mod_num/10:
    digits.append((n - sub_num) // div_a_mod_num % div_a_mod_num) # остальные цифры
    i+=1
    div_a_mod_num*=10
    sub_num+=digits[i]
digits.reverse()

Потом нужно найти максимальное число:
# ------- ищем максимальное число
i=0
for e in digits:
    digits[i] = e
    if e > 7:
        digits[i] = 7
    i+=1

Далее пребразовать цифры обратно в число:
# ------- превращаем список цифр в число
digits.reverse()
i=0
j=1
while i < len(digits):
    y += digits[i] * j
    
    i+=1
    j*=10

И вычислить первое:
# ------- вычисляем первое число
x = n - y

Конечный код:
n = 859 # или другое число
x = 0 # первое слагаемое
y = 0 # второе слагаемое

# ------- делим число на цифры
digits = [] # список для цифр n
digits.append(n % 10) # первая цифра

# для остальных цифр
div_a_mod_num = 10
i=0
sub_num = digits[0] # число для вычета
while n > div_a_mod_num/10:
    digits.append((n - sub_num) // div_a_mod_num % div_a_mod_num) # остальные цифры
    i+=1
    div_a_mod_num*=10
    sub_num+=digits[i]
digits.reverse()

# ------- ищем максимальное число
i=0
for e in digits:
    digits[i] = e
    if e > 7:
        digits[i] = 7
    i+=1

# ------- превращаем список цифр в число
digits.reverse()
i=0
j=1
while i < len(digits):
    y += digits[i] * j
    
    i+=1
    j*=10

# ------- вычисляем первое число
x = n - y

# ------- показ конечного результата
print(x, y)


849 = 72 + 777...

@contrlccontrlc ну так это правильно. он в начале показал 2 примера: 859 = 102 + 757, и 849 = 72 + 777

но твоя программа (или от нейросети) выводит: 102 747

Ну так поменяй 859 на 849 и посмотри на результат...

@contrlccontrlc во первых код я писал сам, во вторых у меня в примере с 859 выводит 102 757

Сори, неправ, сейчас посмотрю и попытаюсь исправить

Это неправильный алгоритм. Тоже с него начинал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1599174/revisions. И тут ещё удалённый ответ есть с таким подходом.

извените, я кучу времени пытался, и результат ничего
